# didReceive UNNotification not getting called

Tags: ios, onesignal, remote-notifications

I have this in my AppDelegate:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest,
                withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    print(request.content.body)
}
```

I am sending a notification through OneSignal using the 'Mutable Content' flag, but this method does not get called. I receive the notification but I would like to change it before it's displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the notifiation being sent is not a **silent notification** due to sending **attachments** or **buttons** alongside the notification. If that's the case then you should alter your implementation. Passing attachments through OneSignal does not require the **mutable-content** flag as the implementation is to wrap the payload into custom fields making the notification silent, then at the client-side replicate the notification via a **UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger**